# How to stop handler when getAccuracy() is lower than 100

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, handler

Hi I am creating an android map application that will get the user location, but when users open their map sometimes the location is not accurate and will slowly pinpoint your location.

I have tried this. But It still calls the handler and the TOASTS won't stop.

```
private LocationManager locationManager;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_page);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              handler.postDelayed(runnable,3000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    });

      private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

      getCurrentLocation();

        Toast.makeText(mapsPage.this, "GETTING LOCATION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
};

   private void getCurrentLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        moveMap();

        Integer loc = Math.round(location.getAccuracy());
        textings.setText(Integer.toString(loc));

        if(loc <= 100)
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

        Toast.makeText(mapsPage.this, "HANDLER STOPPED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
}

//Function to move the map
private void moveMap() {

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(false));

}
```

I have added a handler that will run every 5 seconds checking the users location, and when the getAccuracy data is either equal or lesser than 100 it will stop. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getCurrentLocation may call `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);`, but then the runnable will always call `handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);` right after.

To fix this there has to be some condition for the Runnable to check to see if it should post itself again.

A solution would be to make getCurrentLocation return a boolean indicating if it was successful (enough):

```
private boolean getCurrentLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        moveMap();

        Integer loc = Math.round(location.getAccuracy());
        textings.setText(Integer.toString(loc));

        if(loc <= 100) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            Toast.makeText(mapsPage.this, "HANDLER STOPPED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your Runnable check if you need to have another run:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if(!getCurrentLocation()) {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
}
```

---

**However**, all of that being said, you should just check the Location in onLocationChanged of your LocationListener and do something if that location is accurate enough. Then you don't need the Runnable at all.

Comment: Hey sir I pulled an all nighter with this and I found my answer. I have used a timerTask and replaced toasts with snackbars and it worked really well. I have tried your code and it works, and you deserve an upvote and accepted answer. Thanks again sir for the help and explanation! :D

Comment: But may I ask sir, is my code or approach for pinpointing user location efficient or is I should look into other ways?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely accept RobCo's answer as the correct one because it addresses your question directly and also offers an additional key insight (i.e. you don't really need the Runnable at all).

But, I was curious what RobCo's approach would look like, so I created one possible implementation of it.

It turns out that if we avoid the Runnable and rely on Google's callbacks instead, we can get away with using only the newer location provider API (LocatonServices.FusedLocationApi). The older LocationManager API can just be eliminated.

So, in this implementation, I let the Google location service trigger callbacks if/when the location changes (instead of using a periodic poll from the client):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 10001;
    public static final int LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000; // milliseconds
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void initLocationServices() {
        try {
            // make initial, synchronous request for current location
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if (location != null) {
                moveMap(location);
            }

            // request future location updates which will come in as callbacks later, when available
            LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.w(TAG, "App does not have sufficient permission to request location. " +
                    "Requesting permission now...");
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    private void moveMap(Location location) {
        Log.v(TAG, "moveMap");

        // TODO: actual map moving code goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed:" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "User granted permission. Will request current location.");
            initLocationServices();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "User did not grant permission. Cannot request location. Cannot proceed.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onLocationChanged:" + newLocation.toString());
        moveMap(newLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            initLocationServices();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCreate: requesting sufficient permission from user");
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    }
}
```

A downside of this particular implementation is that the MainActivity implements several interfaces and that adds some confusion (what are all these methods doing here?, etc)

Dunno. Maybe it's useful. In any event, good luck with your app.

Comment: Hey sir, well I have pulled an all nighter and I have found my solution and I am using a timer task now and it works really well. But for the help and explanation sir, you deserve and upvote. Thanks sir for the help!

Comment: But may I ask sir, is my code or approach for pinpointing user location efficient or is your approach more efficient sir?

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution you like. And thank you kindly for the up vote. I'm not sure which approach is the most efficient. In my test app, Google's LocationServices.FusedLocationApi is updating my app every 2 to 5 seconds even though the tablet is just sitting on the desk. So, it's generating a fair number of callbacks. I guess that's similar to a TimerTask asking for location every 5 seconds. In addition, FWIW, if I were implementing the polling approach, I would look for problems and memory leaks when the user puts the app into the background and resumes it.

Comment: So it calls and updates every few seconds even when you don't need it? So I guess I need to set when the map will call updates on the location and when to stop so that it won't be straining the devices battery or other resources. Thanks for the advice sir!

Comment: Yeah. It's interesting. These fused location updates appear to be a bit noisy. So, just sitting on the desk, for example, the tablet's estimated longitude is changing slightly every few seconds in the fourth decimal place, but actually repeating e.g. XX.XXX576, XX.XXX600, XX.XXX576, XX.XXX600, ...

Comment: Thanks for that sir, atleast it gave me an insight on using fused location updates, but it uses alot of resources. haha..